# C++ UE4 - Add child to SSscrollbox

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, scrollbox

I am trying to add dynamically a child in a `SScrollBox` but I get error.

```
TSharedRef<SScrollBox> MainCanvas = SNew(SScrollBox);
TSharedRef < SButton> TestButton = SNew(SButton);

MainCanvas->AddChild(TestButton); //AddChild not defined
```

It seems that addchild is not defined.

How could I add a widget inside scrollbox?

Answer (score 0):

you should use UScrollBox.
UScrollBox is child class of UPanelWidget.
so you can use AddChild(UWidget * Content) function.

also you should use UButton instead of SButton, too.